# What does this colon in tensor notation mean?

Tags: notation, tensors

I was reading a paper earlier an found the following:

"The tensors satisfy orthogonality

$$ <S_{:,j,:,:}|S_{:,j',:,:}> =0 $$
if $j \neq j' $.

Here $<S_{:,j,:,:}|S_{:,j',:,:}>$ is the inner product of these two tensors. They also satisfy pseudodiagonality

$$|S_{:,j,:,:}| \geq |S_{:,j',:,:}| $$ if $j<j'$."

My question is, what do these colons mean? In the first statement it seems like they represent a contraction over their conterpartner in other tensor, such that the first statement could be re-written as $$ S_{i,j,k,l}S_{i,j',k,l}=0 $$ but I'm not quite sure what the second statement means. See equation (7) of this paper http://arxiv.org/abs/1201.1144 /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colon represents a contraction over the same tensor, hence

$$ |T_{i,;}|=\sqrt{\sum_{j}T_{ij}T_{ij}} $$.